# Ray tracing in nonuniform media; did I write this second order differential equation as two first order differential equations correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

Both answers to the Physics SE question [Ray tracing in a inhomogeneous media*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122599/83380) arrive at some form of the equation below and one links to Florian Bociort's dissertation [Imaging properties of gradient-index lenses](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/q1d90/FBweb/diss.pdf) referencing Eq. 2.1.8 and its derivation.

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(n(\mathbf{r}) \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{ds} \right) = \nabla n(\mathbf{r})$$

where $n(\mathbf{r})$ is the index of refraction of a nonuniform material (due to some density gradient for example) and $ds$ is measured along the path that an optical ray would follow in this gradient.

I want to write this as two first order differential equations so I can solve them<sup>1</sup> by numerical integration for arbitrary but well-behaved $n(\mathbf{r})$.

I used

$$\mathbf{f} = n(\mathbf{r}) \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{ds}$$

to write

$$\frac{d\mathbf{f}}{ds} = \nabla n(\mathbf{r})$$

$$\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{ds} = \frac{\mathbf{f}}{n(\mathbf{r})}$$

**Question:** Is this correct? Will numerically solving these two first order differential equations together be a solution to the equation at the beginning? If not, what would be the correct way?

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm already familliar with solving  orbits numerically via the two first order differential equations:

$$\frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt} = \mathbf{a}, \ \ \ \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} = \mathbf{v}$$

where $\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are position, velocity and acceleration respectively.

Comment: I won't have access to this until later today but I have a hunch it may be helpful based on the abstract: [Differential ray tracing in inhomogeneous media](https://www.osapublishing.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-14-10-2824)

Comment: Why do you doubt correctness of this splitting? It's a standard procedure when solving higher-oder DEs numerically.

Comment: @Ruslan I'm one of those people who can't go three lines of algebra without losing a minus sign or transposing some variable from the denominator to the numerator for no reason at all. I suffer from *spurious algebritis* so I suppose I just need some reassurance that I haven't missed anything, be it subtle or glaring. It's very helpful to hear your comment; perhaps next time I will trust my own results without needing to check here first.

Answer (score 1):

Tentative answer as no others have yet been posted:

---

Yes it seems so.

Per [@ruslan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181503/ray-tracing-in-nonuniform-media-did-i-write-this-second-order-differential-equa#comment8667427_4181503):

> Why do you doubt correctness of this splitting? It's a standard procedure when solving higher-oder DEs numerically.

I'd posted the question because I was cautious that it might not be this simple, but it seems that it might be.

Of course there may be some $n(\mathbf{r})$ that are problematic, but for well behaved (e.g. smooth, differentiable, single-valued) functions this should work fine.